# MongoDb - Query an Array

Tags: mongodb

Based on the MongoDB documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/

I have this collection:

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "notebook", qty: 50, tags: ["red", "blank"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "paper", qty: 100, tags: ["red", "blank", "plain"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 22.85, 30 ] },
   { item: "postcard", qty: 45, tags: ["blue"], dim_cm: [ 10, 15.25 ] }
]);
```

Are these queries equivalent ?

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: { $all: ["red"] } } )
```

and

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: "red" } )
```

If they have different purposes , when to use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those two queries are equivalent. You would only use [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) when you want to query for the docs containing multiple `tags` values:

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: { $all: ["red", "blank"] } } )
```

This query would match all but the last document in your example collection.